# Can we descend field extensions of prime degree of number fields to number fields of the same degree

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $K$ be a number field and let $p$ be a prime number.

Let $L$ be a degree $p$ field extension of $K$.

Does there exist a degree $p$ field extension $M$ of $\mathbf{Q}$ such that $$M\otimes_{\mathbf{Q}} K = L?$$

If not, when does this happen?

Does it happen almost always?

I would be willing to hear about any positive thing that can be done in this direction. I'm thinking about Weil restrictions of varieties. That's where this question came up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question can be reformulated as follows.

> Let $L$ be a number field and $p$ a prime. Let $K$ be a subfield of $L$ of index $p$. Does there exist a subfield $M$ of $L$ of order $p$ such that $MK = L$? (One direction of the equivalence is clear; in the other direction, if $MK = L$ then the natural map $M \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} K \to MK$ is an isomorphism by comparing dimensions.)

The answer is not always. If $L$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $C_4$, then $L$ has a unique quadratic subfield, which we'll select as $K$, so it cannot admit a second quadratic subfield $M$. As an explicit example take $L = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ and $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$.

More generally, suppose that $L$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $G$ and write $|G| = pn$. Then by Cauchy's theorem $G$ has an element of order $p$, so the fixed field of this element is a suitable choice for $K$. In order for $M$ to exist, $G$ needs to have subgroups of index $p$, but it may not have any. For example, suppose $L$ has full Galois group $S_n$ (this is the generic case in the sense that the splitting field of a generic irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ has this property) and $n \ge 5$. By the simplicity of $A_n$ it follows that the minimal index of a subgroup of $S_n$ which is not $A_n$ is $n$, so if $p < n$ is an odd prime then $S_n$ has no subgroups of index $p$ and consequently $L$ has no subfields of degree $p$.

On the other hand, we have the following corollary of the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

**Proposition:** Let $M, K$ be subextensions of a Galois extension $L$ (we do not name the base field as it is irrelevant here) with Galois group $G$. Then $MK = L$ if and only if $\text{Gal}(L/M) \cap \text{Gal}(L/K) = \{ e \}$ (where the intersections take place in $G$).

Thus if $|G| = pn$ where $p \nmid n$, then to find $M$ it is necessary and sufficient to find a subgroup of $G$ of index $p$. For example, this is possible if $n = q^k$ for some prime $q \neq p$ by the first Sylow theorem. More generally, it is necessary and sufficient to find a subgroup of index $p$ with trivial intersection with $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ (hence to write $G$ as an internal [Zappa-Szép product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A9p_product) of a cyclic group of order $p$ and some other subgroup).

Comment: Simply amazing...